# How do I get unscaled version of parameter for my interaction model on GLMM using plot_model?

Tags: r, data-analysis, sjplot, glmm

I am looking at camera trap data to study drivers of illegal human activities in the central Vietnam. I made a GLMM model to see the impact of species number and remotessess on the number of human records at each camera trap stations. I used the station as random effect and trap nights as offset. For the analysis I scaled the variables. To see the interaction effect, I used plot_model to get the grapha and it returned the graphs with scaled version of remoteness. How can I get the unscaled version for the resulting image.

I tried plot_model from sjPlot package so far. The part of code looks like this:
plot_model(mod29, type = "pred", terms = c("species_no", "remoteness"),

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Vz7.jpg)

Comment: Hard to tell without either code or sample data (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ). However, you might try setting `plot_model(..., transform = NULL)`: https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/reference/plot_model.html